# How to display a video in a web page using html,php

Tags: html, video

How to display  a video in a web page using html,php,
Any example code
any one will help ,please

Comment: Please use object or embed tag of html just search on google you will find it.

Comment: @Umesh. When people search google they should find this page with a great answer on it. You should try providing the whole solution in an answer.

Comment: Well what kind of video? A video from YouTube or MetaCafe? A video you uploaded on your server? A video that comes from a Windows Media Streaming Server? A video in FLV format?

Answer (score 5):

if you are looking for a flash player, I suggest you [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/).

if you are looking for HTML 5 video take go [there](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2009/07/video-more-than-just-a-tag/)

To embed microsoft videos [here](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/format/windows-media/streaming/embed.html).

I think the best way to embed video is probably flash but if you are an technology enthusiast I would vote for HTML 5 since it's the future.